# Access parent scope in ng-directive

Tags: angularjs

I am out of ideas. How can I get this work?

```
<option data-ng-repeat="item in statusList | 
  orderBy: EventStatus[$parent.ui_language]" value="{{item.EventStatus.id}}">
   {{item.EventStatus[ui_language]}}
</option>
```

I have property ui_language in root scope and it has values 'fin' and 'eng' depending what user language interface user is using. EventStatus is array with correct indexes (fin and eng). Accessing ui_language like above works as excpected inside option tag (this part: `{{item.EventStatus[ui_language]}}`) but I can't it work in orderBy section. What is the trick here?

Answer (score 0):

Directives are supposed to be their own little encapsulated pieces of code.  Trying to access values outside of that is a break in encapsulation principles.

I recommend you set up your directive with a formal isolated scope and pass the ui_language  in as a parameter.  Read the docs on [isolating the scope of a directive.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

You, basically, want to do something like this in your directive function:

```
  scope: {
    ui_language: '='
  },
```

Comment: Ok. How do i "inherit" ng-repeat directive?

Comment: As far as I know; AngularJS Directives do not have an "inherit" in the same way that a Java class may.  Does the ng-repeat not work in your directive? Or does adding the isolated scope prevent it from working?